# Drop shadow not showing up for TextView

Tags: android, textview, drop-shadow

I've tried the following code but the drop shadow will not show up, it just appears as regular white text.

```
TextView newsTitle = new TextView(mCtx);
newsTitle.setText(newsitems[position].getTitle());
newsTitle.setTextAppearance(mCtx, R.style.TextWithDropShadow);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newsTitleParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
newsTitleParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, linLayout.getId());
newsTitleParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
newsTitle.setLayoutParams(newsTitleParams);
relLayout.addView(newsTitle);
```

And the style file is

```
<style name="TextWithDropShadow">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
```

Is there an issue with relative layouts and drop shadows perhaps?

Comment: maybe you should try to lower the blur radius(shadowRadius) to 0.1 - 0.3 to see it

Comment: Had no effect.  The shadow doesn't appear at all, even with changing those values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this doesn't answer the problem at hand, a different approach works.

Adding this line

```
newsTitle.setShadowLayer(15, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

Would still be interesting to know what I was doing wrong using the styles.